# whats the difference?:Integrated Circuits vs combinational circuit and sequential circuit

Tags: cpu-architecture

As per my understanding, (in terms of Computer Architecture by Moris Mano 3rd edition), a combinational circuit is a group of Gates, whereas sequential circuit is a group of Gates plus flip-flops. 
On the hand Integrated Circuits also consist of interconnected Gates, so does that mean they are same?

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorial circuit - a circuit whose output is always fully defined by its current outputs (has no memory)

Sequential circuit - a circuit whose output may depend on the history of the previous inputs.

Integrated circuit - a circuit implemented as a single silicon wafer (or other material). Some integrated circuits are combinatorial, some are sequential. For the official definition, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit